# Ubuntu freezing with command sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1

Tags: 16.04, docker

I am trying to learn docker on Ubuntu 16.04 and I am following the get-started guide and I reached [part-4](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/).

The first time I managed to create the virtual machines with the command

```
sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1
```

Going on I messed up with something and the file config.json was corrupted so I deleted the .docker folder and re-installed the command for docker-machine.

After that I tried to recreate the virtual machines with the command above and every time the OS freezes (it does not respond neither with the mouse nor with the keyboard). The last output on the Terminal is

```
Check network to re-create if needed
```

I have tried to reinstall even virtualbox but nothing happened.
Does anyone have any suggestion?

EDIT: For those who still have this problem I have noticed creating new vm with different names works. I know this is not a solution but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed:**

Change Virtualbox-5.0 to [Virutalbox-5.2](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

**Ubuntu 16.04**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)